# wordpress very slow on docker but on windows wamp very fast

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I have local WordPress website on windows with Wamp server that have normal speed on load pages. I copy this website (with duplicator plugin) to linux (centos) and run with docker that too slow for load any pages(in local) as shown as.

Notes:

1. I copy web sit on another folder Wamp server and that was very fast again.
2. I disabled all plugins but yet so slow.

image slow pages

[image: 1]

Composer file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:

  db:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: sql
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mypasswordpress
      MYSQL_USER: mypasswordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypasswordpress
    networks:
      - my-net
        
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:php8.2
    container_name: site
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - ./html:/var/www/html
      
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: mypass
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: mypass
    networks:
      - my-net
    depends_on:
      - db

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    container_name: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '81:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: 900M
      MEMORY_LIMIT: 1000M
      MAX_EXECUTION_TIME: 3000
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypass 
    networks:
      - my-net
    depends_on:
      - db

networks:
  my-net:
```

Comment: Change MAX_EXECUTION_TIME: 3000 to a lowe value, 30 for example

Comment: I change but no effect.

Comment: Did you rebuild, or what ever the correct term for docker, haven't used it in a while

Comment: @Buttered_Toast I use `docker-compose  up -d` or `docker-compose  restart -d`

Comment: Changes to your composer config file will take affect only after you rebuild it

Comment: how can i rebuild that with out clear wordpress data?

Comment: Do a backup first, files and DB. Then google it, I honestly don't remember how. But make sure to backup

Comment: I run `docker-compose  down -d`  after `docker-compose  up -d` but not effect .